# Table format in a cell using csv module in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, format

I'm trying to format a table in a cell using the CSV module, but for some reason, the numbers aren't aligning up with the text. I've tried using the format string with the old method and the new method, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on how I could get these numbers to align with the text? Thanks.

Code:

```
variant_id = category['variantSetId']
sizes = "{}\n{}".format(
    " ".join(
        ["%-20i" % size['variantId'] for size in category['sizes']]),
    " ".join(
        ["%-20s" % size['text'] for size in category['sizes']])
)

writer.writerow((variant_id, sizes))
```

CSV Output

[image: CSV Output]

Comment: instead of posting a picture, consider copying and pasting the output code, and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Marcos It wouldn't let me post a table.

Comment: I’m voting to close this as typo/can’t be reproduced, as the issue is that OP wasn’t using a monospace font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that (despite mixing old and new style format string syntax which could be considered bad style) your code works perfect. The only reason, numbers and text dont line up, is that you are not displaying it with a mono space font.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that individual characters have different widths in a non-monospace font and yeah I normally don't mix formatting up like that.. I was just trying things working.